# Basic concept in the following WCF article

Tags: wcf, blogs, article

I am a bit confused with this paticular blog post here...
http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/13/4417.aspx

What is his concept of tunelling? I mean how is he able to access port 110 on WCF client through HTTP from the WCF server?

I don't get that part.

Thanks.

Edit : I understand the fact that he's creating a pop3 client on the WCF server and pop3 server on the WCF client. But,how is he accomplishing the VPN part? 110 without NAT? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What he has done is created a WCF client that implements the pop3 protocol and a WCF server that also implements the pop3 protocol. The WCF client can communicate to the server using plain old HTTP which is allowed by most firewals. So now the way it works is his mail client talks to the WCF client using pop3 both on localhost so that it can access port110 regardless of the firewall settings of the network he is on. The WCF client talks to the WCF server using HTTP. The WCF server (which is on a network that allows accessing port 110) talks to the original pop3 server he is trying to get mail from using POP3. There is no NAT or VPN involved. If it's not clear add a comment and I will try to expand.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply...but how is he connecting from the pop3 client to pop3 server?

Comment: I can see the code...he's initiating WCF connection to the WCF service...and the pop3 server is running on the WCF client....

Comment: TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port); He's trying to connect to the WCF client from the WCF server right? how is he doing it and where?

Comment: Ok,I'll tell you why I'm looking at this article...its because I want to perform 2 way communication through HTTP across various clients with seperate session for each client.I thought I'll use his concept and replace pop3 with remoting. I think once I understand how the pop3 client part works,I can replace it with remoting

Comment: The code is incomplete look at the diagram it's only for the red part. His concept will not ever send a request from the server to the client. So it's not a good example for what you are after. And why are you trying to combine remoting and WCF? Remoting sort of became obsolete with WCF. I think you are best of creating a new question asking for what you actually are trying to accomplish instead of what you are doing now.

Comment: I see you did that already at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317697/wcf-two-way-http-communication-to-bypass-firewalls

Comment: I've already asked two questions....sounds like no one knows the solution...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318229/easiest-for-two-way-communication-over-the-internet-using-c


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317697/wcf-two-way-http-communication-to-bypass-firewalls

Comment: yeah.....I've been trying for quite a while and I don't have a solid assured solution yet...

Comment: I answered your other question.

Comment: Did you see all the parts of his article..
"http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/13/4417.aspx"
"http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/13/4418.aspx"
"http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/13/4419.aspx"
"http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/13/4420.aspx"